# Where can I buy authentic cheongsachorong (청사초롱) - traditional lanterns - in Seoul?

Tags: shopping, south-korea, seoul, souvenirs

Cheongsachorong (청사초롱) are traditional lanterns, originally used for weddings in Korea.
They are made of red and blue silk.

[image: Cheongsachorong from a traditional roof]
*Cheongsachorong* By Minseong Kim (Own work) [CC BY-SA 4.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0)], via Wikimedia Commons

Where can I buy an authentic version of these - ideally in Seoul, or elsewhere in Korea?

Comment: @Closevoters: how is this a "Question on price-shopping for specific goods or services"?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm There's an ongoing debate on meta wrt the interpretation of that close reason -- price-shopping or just plain shopping. [Come read it.](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3295/price-shopping-or-shopping-questions)

Answer (score 5):

While I couldn't locate any permanent shops online, there's one event where you can certainly get a lantern: [Seoul Lantern Festival](http://seoullantern.visitseoul.net/). It's an annual festival held every November in Seoul. The official website [lists prices](http://www.visitseoul.net/en/article/article.do?_method=view&art_id=82907&lang=en&m=0004021006001&p=21) for many different kinds of lanterns:

> Rectangular lanterns: KRW 15,000 / Hanji lantern (3 types): KRW 10,000 / Color lanterns: KRW 5,000

I therefore presume that there is official lantern store on the grounds where you can get a cheongsachorong.